# How do I access the `addr2line` functionality within my C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, linux, backtrace, addr2line

I need to get the information provided by addr2line (source file and line from backtracing a function call) from within a C++ program.

I know I can call addr2line directly as a subprocess and I know that I can copy [the source code of addr2line](https://web.archive.org/web/20100916204325/http://www.koders.com/c/fid79D38B0848AFE045E3A0B6457DE1653F972671E3.aspx) into my program (which is also GPL licensed). But the code looks complicated and I don't feel comfortable using it directly. What does `bfd` mean, anyway? I would prefer to use some function in the C++ STL library, because that would be cleaner.

I am working in a Linux environment.

Comment: libdwarf is what youre looking for

Comment: Thankd for the suggestion. I tried dwarfdump and it only prints where functions are declared, not where they are called. I couldn't find a decent documentation though...

Comment: `bfd` is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_File_Descriptor_library (although originally it stood for the other meaning of BFD :)

Comment: You can see the can see the calls addr2line makes with `ltrace`, but you might not want to link against bfd directly yourself: http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2005/05/msg01086.html

Comment: doh! So my only way is to call popen("addr2line","r") and parse the output!

Comment: Here you have a working implementation. https://github.com/albfan/bindutils-gdb/issues/1. Now is a system call, but its goal is to create a addr2line library. Seems pretty easy!

Answer (score 7):

You can try the function `dladdr()`. It uses the dynamic symbols of the program, not the debugging information (compile the program with `gcc -rdynamic`).

Also, you can check the [backtrace](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) library, or the higher level [stacktrace](http://stacktrace.sourceforge.net/) library.
Not exactly what you are asking, but they may prove useful.

Comment: Thank you for the tipps. With `dladdr()` I get information only for dynamically linked code and only the filename, not the line, if I understand the manpage right. I am already using backtrace to get the address. What I need now is something to get the file and line out of the address. stacktrace is a mere wrapper for backtrace.

Comment: In addition to these, there is also the `libunwind` library: http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/

Comment: @ArtoBendiken libunwind doesn't have an addr2line-like functionality. It only provides the offset

Answer (score 6):

Check the source code of bsd implementation of addr2line, it has only about 400 lines code. Change the source to a library function should be very easy. http://sourceforge.net/p/elftoolchain/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/addr2line/addr2line.c