# Is there a way to dump stack trace with line number from a Linux release binary?

Tags: c++, linux, backtrace

I have a requirement of dumping stack traces when my c++ Linux application crashes. I was successfully able to do this using `backtrace()` and `backtrace_symbols()`. Now, additionally I would like to get the line numbers of the crash. How do it do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15132424/841108 is a very similar question by same author.

Comment: So, what did you eventually do?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'd keep it as two separate questions. In fact, the OP should be praised for splitting the queries into two fairly orthogonal questions like this.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636456/how-to-get-a-stack-trace-for-c-using-gcc-with-line-number-information On crash handler specific: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77005/how-to-automatically-generate-a-stacktrace-when-my-program-crashes

Answer (score 19):

I took help from

http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/063/6391/6391l2.html
and http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6391?page=0,0 to come up with sample code which shows how you can achieve this.

Basically  it is about putting a stack backtrace inside a signal handler and having the latter catch all the "bad" signals your program can receive (SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, SIGILL, SIGFPE and the like). This way, if your program unfortunately crashes and you were not running it with a debugger, you can get a stack trace and know where the fault happened. This technique also can be used to understand where your program is looping in case it stops responding...

Below code runs the external program [addr2line](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/addr2line1.html) for every address in the trace to convert it into a file name and a line number.

The source code below prints line numbers for all local functions. If a function from another library is called, you might see a couple of ??:0 instead of file names.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <execinfo.h>

void bt_sighandler(int sig, struct sigcontext ctx) {

  void *trace[16];
  char **messages = (char **)NULL;
  int i, trace_size = 0;

  if (sig == SIGSEGV)
    printf("Got signal %d, faulty address is %p, "
           "from %p\n", sig, ctx.cr2, ctx.eip);
  else
    printf("Got signal %d\n", sig);

  trace_size = backtrace(trace, 16);
  /* overwrite sigaction with caller's address */
  trace[1] = (void *)ctx.eip;
  messages = backtrace_symbols(trace, trace_size);
  /* skip first stack frame (points here) */
  printf("[bt] Execution path:\n");
  for (i=1; i<trace_size; ++i)
  {
    printf("[bt] #%d %s\n", i, messages[i]);

    char syscom[256];
    sprintf(syscom,"addr2line %p -e sighandler", trace[i]); //last parameter is the name of this app
    system(syscom);
  }

  exit(0);
}


int func_a(int a, char b) {

  char *p = (char *)0xdeadbeef;

  a = a + b;
  *p = 10;  /* CRASH here!! */

  return 2*a;
}


int func_b() {

  int res, a = 5;

  res = 5 + func_a(a, 't');

  return res;
}


int main() {

  /* Install our signal handler */
  struct sigaction sa;

  sa.sa_handler = (void *)bt_sighandler;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;

  sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
  sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
  /* ... add any other signal here */

  /* Do something */
  printf("%d\n", func_b());
}
```

This code should be compiled as: gcc sighandler.c -o sighandler -rdynamic

The program outputs:

```
Got signal 11, faulty address is 0xdeadbeef, from 0x8048975
[bt] Execution path:
[bt] #1 ./sighandler(func_a+0x1d) [0x8048975]
/home/karl/workspace/stacktrace/sighandler.c:44
[bt] #2 ./sighandler(func_b+0x20) [0x804899f]
/home/karl/workspace/stacktrace/sighandler.c:54
[bt] #3 ./sighandler(main+0x6c) [0x8048a16]
/home/karl/workspace/stacktrace/sighandler.c:74
[bt] #4 /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6) [0x3fdbd6]
??:0
[bt] #5 ./sighandler() [0x8048781]
??:0
```

Comment: Piece of cake! Notice you forget to add `-g` to compile. Seeing addr2line implementation should be easy to create a library call to avoid a system call. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556321/is-there-a-library-call-to-addr2line.

Comment: use the system call outside of the for loop with the following call: addr2line -psfCe sighandler <list_of_addresses>

Comment: This answer will only work if addr2line is available in the file system.

Comment: This is Intel-specific code - won't play with TX1, TX2, Xavier, Nano, or any PI stuff.

Answer (score 3):

It is only possible if the program has been compiled with debugging information (i.e. with `gcc -Wall -g` or with `g++ -Wall -g`). Without `-g` the executable does not contain any source line information. And if using `gcc` you can compile with both optimization & debugging information (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g -O2`) but sometimes the line location would be "surprising".

<sup>The `-Wall` flag asks GCC to show all warnings. It is very useful (hence my recommendation to use it) but unrelated to `-g` or debugging information.</sup>

As to how to extract the line number, the simplest way would be to fork a `gdb` process. Alternatively, you could get the debugging information (in [DWARF](http://www.dwarfstd.org/) format) and parse it, perhaps using `libdwarf` from the [ELF tool chain](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/elftoolchain/). I am not sure it is worth the trouble...

To just get the backtrace, you might simply run your program thru `gdb` perhaps as `gdb --args yourprogram itsarguments`...

---

#### addenda

you could also use the [libbacktrace](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libbacktrace/) from inside a recent GCC (actually it is [Ian Taylor's libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace)), which is designed to solve your problem (it is "interpreting" the DWARF format of the current executable, which you would compile with `g++ -O -g`).

Comment: Spawning another process, especially gdb, cannot be considered a "simple way" of doing things...

Answer (score 2):

`system()` needs `#include <stdlib.h>`

Few other things seem missing.

```
$ g++-8 -g -o dump dump.cpp
dump.cpp: In function ‘void bt_sighandler(int, sigcontext)’:
dump.cpp:15:43: error: ‘struct sigcontext’ has no member named
‘eip’; did > you mean ‘rip’?
         "from %p\n", sig, ctx.cr2, ctx.eip);
                                        ^~~
                                        rip
dump.cpp:21:26: error: ‘struct sigcontext’ has no member
named ‘eip’;
did you mean ‘rip’?
  trace[1] = (void *)ctx.eip;
                         ^~~
                         rip
dump.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
dump.cpp:64:19: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to
   ‘__sighandler_t’ > {aka ‘void (*)(int)’} [-fpermissive]
   sa.sa_handler = (void *)bt_sighandler;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: of course it be like that he compile it on 32-bit system rather 64-bit system for the `eip`

Answer (score 1):

As Saqlain pointed out, addr2line can be used to get the line number.

If a library is preferred, take a look at the [LPT kit](https://freeshell.de/~amelinte/software.html). Instructions on how to install are at [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linux_Applications_Debugging_Techniques/Building_the_toolkit). LPT relies on the bfd library.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I have a Xavier (NVIDIA Jetpack 4.4 Ubuntu 18.04.5) open in front of me when I tripped over this nice note. I was chagrined to discover that this code did not work on Xavier, which is basically an aarch64 architecture and some of these signal structures are different.

So I managed to cobble together a counterexample that works both on X86_64 and aarch64.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <ucontext.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef __aarch64__
#define _PC pc
#define _SP sp
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
#define _PC gregs[REG_RSP]
#define _SP gregs[REG_RIP]
#else
#error architecture not supported
#endif

static void addr2line(void *traceP, void *messageP) {
  char syscom[256];
#ifdef __aarch64__
  char message[4096];
  strcpy(message, (char *) messageP);
  char *saveP = NULL, *token = strtok_r(message, "(", &saveP);
  if(token) {
    token = strtok_r(NULL, "+", &saveP);
    if(token) {
      char *term = strchr(token,')');
      if(term)
        *term = 0;
    }
  }
  if(token==NULL) {
    token = message;
  }
  sprintf(syscom,"addr2line %s -e sighandler", token);
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
  sprintf(syscom,"addr2line %p -e sighandler", traceP); //last parameter is the name of this app
#endif
  system(syscom);
}

void bt_sighandler(int sig, siginfo_t *psi, void *ctxarg) {

  void *trace[16];
  char **messages = (char **)NULL;
  int i, trace_size = 0;
  mcontext_t *ctxP = &((ucontext_t *) ctxarg)->uc_mcontext;

  if (sig == SIGSEGV)
    printf("Got signal %d, faulty address is %p, "
           "from %p\n", sig, (void *) ctxP->_PC, (void *) ctxP->_SP);
  else
    printf("Got signal %d\n", sig);

  trace_size = backtrace(trace, 16);
  /* overwrite sigaction with caller's address */
  trace[1] = (void *)ctxP->_SP;

  messages = backtrace_symbols(trace, trace_size);
  /* skip first stack frame (points here) */
  printf("[bt] Execution path:\n");
  for (i=1; i<trace_size; ++i)
  {
    printf("[bt] #%d %s\n", i, messages[i]);

    addr2line(trace[i], messages[i]);
  }

  exit(0);
}


int func_a(int a, char b) {

  char *p = (char *)0xdeadbeef;

  a = a + b;
  *p = 10;  /* CRASH here!! */

  return 2*a;
}


int func_b() {

  int res, a = 5;

  res = 5 + func_a(a, 't');

  return res;
}


int main() {

  /* Install our signal handler */
  struct sigaction sa;

  sa.sa_sigaction = bt_sighandler;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO;

  sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
  sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
  /* ... add any other signal here */

  /* Do something */
  printf("%d\n", func_b());
}
```

Basically:

- the signal handler includes SA_INFO, which is structured differently, but looks to be supported in both architectures. Note the signal handler must populate sa_sigaction rather than sa_handler.
- the third parameter on the signal handler "void *ctxarg" is cast to a ucontext_t which includes an mcontext_t which includes the PC and SP fields. These are structured differently in the x86_64 and aarch64 architectures, and so the code has to be architecture-specific.
- add2line does not work with the addresses provided in trace[i]. I have not found why - these addresses are prefixed with 0x55 - if you strip off this offset they work, but where it comes from is currently a mystery to me. However, the message[i] includes an offset that can be used in its place, just requires some string manipulation to acquire it.
- There is an extra entry in the backtrace (didn't go looking for an explanation why)

The code now runs on x86_64 and gives similiar, usable results.

```
xavier $ ./sighandler 3
Got signal 11, faulty address is 0x5563baadf4, from 0x7fd4439350
[bt] Execution path:
[bt] #1 [0x7fd4439350]
??:0
[bt] #2 ./sighandler(+0xdf4) [0x5563baadf4]
/home/jsaari/project/radar_ars/alfalfa/cuda/debug/sighandler.cpp:79
[bt] #3 ./sighandler(+0xe24) [0x5563baae24]
/home/jsaari/project/radar_ars/alfalfa/cuda/debug/sighandler.cpp:89
[bt] #4 ./sighandler(+0xea4) [0x5563baaea4]
/home/jsaari/project/radar_ars/alfalfa/cuda/debug/sighandler.cpp:109
[bt] #5 /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe0) [0x7f9ae316e0]
??:0
[bt] #6 ./sighandler(+0xa94) [0x5563baaa94]
:?


x86_64 $ ./sighandler 3
Got signal 11, faulty address is 0x7ffe291d27d0, from 0x40095a
[bt] Execution path:
[bt] #1 ./sighandler() [0x40095a]
/home/jsaari/common/experiment/backtrace/sighandler.cpp:79
[bt] #2 ./sighandler() [0x40095a]
/home/jsaari/common/experiment/backtrace/sighandler.cpp:79
[bt] #3 ./sighandler() [0x400982]
/home/jsaari/common/experiment/backtrace/sighandler.cpp:89
[bt] #4 ./sighandler() [0x4009f4]
/home/jsaari/common/experiment/backtrace/sighandler.cpp:109
[bt] #5 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7f294a36d495]
??:0
[bt] #6 ./sighandler() [0x4006d9]
??:?
```

**IMHO - Now that NVIDIA has acquired ARM, ARM WILL TAKE OVER THE INTERNET-OF-THINGS (if it hasn't already), and Intel is likely to start struggling.**

---

Apparently, there is an address scrambling going on as documented here:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=860394

Apparently, this is caused by gcc building ONLY position-independent code. If you build the app with "-no-pie", then the trace[i] entries work with addr2line.

I have not found how to manage this aside from the process I coded.

---

From this posting:

[How to find load relocation for a PIE binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55066749/how-to-find-load-relocation-for-a-pie-binary)

The relocation value can be obtained from

```
#include <link.h>

. . .

uintptr_t relocation = _r_dump.r_map->l_addr;
```

The relocation value can be subtracted from trace[i] to get an address that addr2line can make use of (result on xavier aarch64 box I'm using).

For a non-relocation binary, the value of relocation is "0" (result on the x86_64 box I'm using).