# Stacktrace file and line position

Tags: c++, c, backtrace

so there are quite some question about this already and thank to threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129089/is-there-a-way-to-dump-stack-trace-with-line-number-from-a-linux-release-binary) I have the file and line number kind of working.

The issue is that I am not getting what I was expecting in some case and try to figure out why and if there is a way to work around it.

Example

```
typedef struct _sig_ucontext {
    unsigned long uc_flags;
    struct ucontext *uc_link;
    stack_t uc_stack;
    struct sigcontext uc_mcontext;
    sigset_t uc_sigmask;
} sig_ucontext_t;

void crit_err_hdlr(int sig_num, siginfo_t * info, void * ucontext)
{
    void * array[50];
    void * caller_address;
    char ** messages;
    int size, i;
    sig_ucontext_t * uc;

    uc = (sig_ucontext_t *) ucontext;

    /* Get the address at the time the signal was raised */
#if defined(__i386__) // gcc specific
    caller_address = (void *) uc->uc_mcontext.eip; // EIP: x86 specific
#elif defined(__x86_64__) // gcc specific
    caller_address = (void *) uc->uc_mcontext.rip; // RIP: x86_64 specific
#endif

    fprintf(stderr, "signal %d (%s), address is %p from %p\n", sig_num, strsignal(sig_num), info->si_addr, (void *) caller_address);

    size = backtrace(array, 50);

    /* overwrite sigaction with caller's address */
    array[1] = caller_address;

    messages = backtrace_symbols(array, size);

    /* skip first stack frame (points here) */
    for (i = 1; i < size && messages != NULL; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[bt]: (%d) %s\n", i, messages[i]);

        char syscom[256];
        sprintf(syscom, "addr2line %p -e GEBMerge", array[i]);
        system(syscom);
    }

    free(messages);

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I prepare the signal handler then I have the *main* function.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //     std::cerr << "Entering main function of GEBMerge.cxx...\n";

    struct sigaction sigact;

    sigact.sa_sigaction = crit_err_hdlr;
    sigact.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO;

    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sigact, (struct sigaction *) NULL) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error setting signal handler for %d (%s)\n",
        SIGSEGV, strsignal(SIGSEGV));

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int* crash = 0;
    *crash = 666;

    return 0;
}
```

This will produce

```
signal 11 (Segmentation fault), address is (nil) from 0x402423
[bt]: (1) ./GEBMerge(main+0x43) [0x402423]
/mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/ORNL/software/goddess_daq/source/GEBMerge.cxx:245
[bt]: (2) ./GEBMerge(main+0x43) [0x402423]
/mnt/hgfs/Dropbox/ORNL/software/goddess_daq/source/GEBMerge.cxx:245
[bt]: (3) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7fd58e7c1830]
??:0
[bt]: (4) ./GEBMerge(_start+0x29) [0x402519]
??:?
```

Which seems fine (even though I am not sure why the first line appears twice).

But then if I use this in the *main* instead

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //     std::cerr << "Entering main function of GEBMerge.cxx...\n";

    struct sigaction sigact;

    sigact.sa_sigaction = crit_err_hdlr;
    sigact.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO;

    if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sigact, (struct sigaction *) NULL) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "error setting signal handler for %d (%s)\n",
        SIGSEGV, strsignal(SIGSEGV));

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* crash = 0;
    sprintf(crash, "crash it damit!");

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following

```
signal 11 (Segmentation fault), address is (nil) from 0x403503
[bt]: (1) ./GEBMerge(main+0x73) [0x403503]
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:34
[bt]: (2) ./GEBMerge(main+0x73) [0x403503]
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:34
[bt]: (3) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) 
[0x7f5f74ba9830]
??:0
[bt]: (4) ./GEBMerge(_start+0x29) [0x406169]
??:?
```

I understand why the line `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:34` appears (linked to the sprintf function I assume) but I was expecting to see, somewhere in this stacktrace, a reference to the line calling *sprintf* in the *main* of my program.

I guess there is something I am missing but cannot figure out what.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you compile with debugging symbols enabled (`-g`)?

Comment: I always use `-g3`, personally - depending on the compiler.

Comment: Since you tagged this a C++ and are programming in C++, get rid of the `typedef` before a struct, as it is not needed in C++.  You also don't need the `struct` keyword when declaring a variable.

Comment: You should also use `std::string` instead of `char *`.  With pointers, you have to deal with ownership and maybe deep copy as well as always allocating space for the character array.  You can pass a `std::string` by reference so no copies are made and you don't need to worry about ownership or misplaced pointers.

Comment: You might try adding the flag -rdynamic to your compiler and linker arguments; I find that helps generate more useful stack traces.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: if I don't put struct then it interprets it as the function sigaction. For the typedef I agree, I just copied something from another answer but don't think it's what's causing the "issue" here? Finally I am using the char* just to illustrate the question, which is about where addr2line points when printing the stack trace

Comment: @nemequ: I did compile with -g

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner: I'll try the -rdynamic